# Java Selenium - How to interact with id-less/class-less element?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, automation

I'm trying to interact with a button on a page. `Linktext` and `xpath` do not work, there are no classes or combinations of selecting elements and looping through them I can find that work.

Here is the screen shot of the code I'm trying to do a `.click()`

[image]

Please help me how do i achieve the same ?

Comment: which xpath you have tried ? plz mentioned the same also add the `html` instead of image.

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: angular I believe

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options as below. I simplified your example HTML code to smoke test these queries:

1. Select an element based on its content. The drawback is of course that as soon as "Historical Scans" label changes to something else your query will stop working.

   //nav[@id='secondaryNav']//ul[contains(@class, "menu")]//a[normalize-space(.)="Historical Scans"]

(working example on xpath tester http://xpather.com/dqZ7UWvz)

2. Select an element based on the position on the list. The downside is that it will stop working once this element changes its position.

   //nav[@id='secondaryNav']//ul[contains(@class, "menu")]/li[3]/a

(http://xpather.com/rgexHKBB)

Based on my experience you should not rely on any other attributes or elements. Ideally, the best option would be to add ids/classes. Please let us know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have tried selecting by xpath with both of these options and a NoSuchElementException is thrown in both cases. I would really like to avoid clicking coordinates on the browser but I am running out of options.

Comment: Please paste the HTML code of the whole page or maybe just a bigger part of it.

Comment: I also see that the page uses angularjs, maybe the element is not yet visible when the selenium is trying to click it? (for example ng-show directive drives the visibility of an element)

Comment: I had to censor parts because its not mine to be sharing.  It looks like those potions I find in the inspector are not in the html source.  The code is too long to post here.

Comment: Please try instead: //nav[@id='secondaryNav']//ul[contains(@class, "menu")]//a[normalize-space(.)="Historical Scans"] or just //a[normalize-space(.)="Historical Scans"] I updated my previous answer, I have no better ideas (I added normalize-space). It definitely should work if this element is displayed when selenium tries to find it.

Comment: Please make sure that the element is available when Selenium tries to find it. Maybe implicit or explicit waits should be used: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits In general testing angularjs apps using Selenium only can be tricky. We used https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver in one of our projects to solve problems with AJAX queries and HTML changes that angularjs make when receiving responses. This looks like a similar problem.

Comment: This is interesting, let me try ngwebdriver and I'll get back.